# Identify and assign most recent file to shell variable

Tags: bash, files, timestamps

I have a directory of `.jpg` files that continuously grows. I want to copy the most recent one elsewhere. This is what I currently have and it works, just curious if there's a better way to identify the most recent jpg file rather than using `ls` and `tail`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/JPGS
fn=$(ls -rt1 | tail -1)
mv -f $fn /home/pi/WWW/webpic.jpg
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a number of characters in file names that would make that fail. You can improve it with:

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd /home/pi/JPGS || exit
fn=$(ls -t | head -n1)
mv -f -- "$fn" /home/pi/WWW/webpic.jpg
```

Leaving a variable unquoted in list context (in Bourne-like shells other than `zsh`) is the split+glob operator, you almost never want to do that. `--` marks the end of the options so `"$fn"` will not be taken as an option if it starts with `-`.

That still fails if filenames contain newline characters, but not space, tab, star, question mark, right square bracket, or start with dash.

Best is to use `zsh` here:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
mv -f /home/pi/JPGS/*.jpg(.om[1]) /home/pi/WWW/webpic.jpg
```

`(.om[1])` are glob qualifiers, they are a `zsh` specific feature. `.` restricts the glob to regular files (will not include symlinks, directories, devices...), `om` is to **o**rder on **m**odification time, and `[1]` to only take the first file.

Note that if you want to assign that to a shell variable, that would have to be an array variable:

```
fn=(/home/pi/JPGS/*.jpg(.om[1]))
```

(not that it makes a lot of difference on how you use it later).

Comment: Thanks - I have a few questions: What's the significance of the `--` and why is zsh preferable over bash here? I'm also not sure `(.om[1])` does.

Comment: @Levon, answer updated with details.

Comment: Thanks .. good to store this away for future possible use, my filenames are quite regular so I won't have to worry about special cases for this.

Comment: @Levon, that's no reason (IMO) to use the wrong syntax. You should really get used to not writing things like `mv $f xx` which is the wrong syntax and bad practice (and where most of the shell-related vulnerabilities come from) but `mv -- "$f" xx`

Comment: You are right of course, my comment was with regard to the globing, not re `--` which is clearly important from a security standpoint too - thanks again

Comment: instead of "ls -t" you could perhaps use "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n1" to limit to regular files...

Comment: @hajikelist, that would not sort the list by modification time.

Answer (score 8):

#### Listing file

You could reverse the logic on the `ls` a bit.

```
$ ls -t | head -n1
```

#### Details

```
   -t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

Now it shows up first so we can use `head` to return the first result.

**NOTE:** You could also sort the list by change time (ctime), though you're probably going to want to use modify time above - (mtime). The ctime is the last time the file status meta information was changed.

```
   -c     with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of 
          file status information) with -l: show ctime and sort by name
          otherwise: sort by ctime, newest first
```

For example:

```
$ ls -tc | head -n1
```

#### Moving the file

To do the move more cleanly you'll want to wrap the filename in double quotes.

#### Example

```
$ mv -f -- "$fn" /home/pi/WWW/webpic.jpg
```

This will work in the majority of cases, there are a handful of legal filenames where it won't, for example, files with new lines. But these, though legal, are rarely ever intentionally used.

Comment: Thanks - I do know the filenames, so this won't be an issue.  What is the advantage of using double-quotes around the variable?

Comment: he'll probably want to sort on `mtime` (which reflects the modification time of the content of the file) rather than `ctime` (which reflects the modification time of metadata as well).

Comment: Note that, portably (and as the documentation you quote mentions), you need the `-t` option as well: `ls -tc` to _sort_ on the inode-change time (and `ls -lc` to _display_ the inode-change time, and `ls -ut` to sort on access time)

Comment: @Levon - double quotes protects the `mv` command in cases where there are spaces within the file names.

Comment: Thanks, very useful info re the use of "" .. my current filenames won't have that problem, but I will start using this as the default way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the most recent file with a `jpg` suffix, wherever it is, to a shell variable:

`fn=$( locate .jpg | xargs ls -rt | tail -1)`

Thanks to locate, this is quick even if you have a large number of files. Main drawback: files modified since the last update of the locate database are not taken into account.

Another drawback: does not behave well when there is no file with `.jpg` (because of ls).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'd use find as it is more general. I just ran into a
variant of this, determining the newest executable but it comes up in other places. The find command,

```
find .. -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -g
```

should be quite flexible and work with any file names.
Change the path and criteria as you need and then tail the output.

Although I admit for my case I ended up with,

```
EXIF=`ls -t \`which -a exiftool \` | awk '{print $1}' `


which -a setup
/home/scripts/setup
/home/scripts/lat/scripts/setup
/home/documents/latex/scripts/setup
marchywka@happy$ ls -t `which -a setup `
/home/scripts/setup /home/documents/latex/scripts/setup /home/scripts/lat/scripts/setup
marchywka@happy$ ls -alt `ls -t \`which -a setup \` `
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 897 Oct  8 17:54 /home/scripts/setup
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 166 Sep 13 13:50 
/home/scripts/lat/scripts/setup
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 163 Jan 27  2019 /home/documents/latex/scripts/setup
```